# Searching for mac files of same name but in a different format

Tags: mac, search, file

I have a batch of files and need to search/gather files of the same name but in another format (as opposed to manually searching for the files which would take forever!),

eg. I have a list such as
fredbloggs.pdf
joesmith.pdf
benjones.pdf

..and need to find on my mac
fredbloggs.txt
joesmith.txt
benjones.txt

..is there any software out there that can match up files like this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried entering the name in spotlight search ?

Answer (score 2):

You can just type `kind:txt` in finder search. This will give you all of the txt files on your system.

Answer (score 0):

One simple possibility (albeit requiring usage of Terminal app) is to enter something like:

```
find . -name 'fredbloggs.*'
```

Example with dummy files:

[image]